# Empty "release" ASSERT macro crashes program?

Tags: c++, macros

Take a look at this code:

```
#include <cassert>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define ASSERT(expr) assert(expr)
#else
#define ASSERT(expr)
#endif /* DEBUG */
```

The program will run only if I have `DEBUG` defined, otherwise it will hang and terminate with no results. I am using MinGW in Eclipse Indigo CDT. Advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost certainly **abusing assertions**. An assertion expression *must never have side effects*.

When you say, `assert(initialize_critical_space_technology());`, and then you omit this entire line in the release build, you can imagine for yourself what will happen.

The only safe and sane way to use assertions is on values:

```
const bool space_init = initialize_critical_space_technology();
assert(space_init);
```

Some people introduce a `VERIFY` macro for something that always executes the code:

```
#define VERIFY(x) (x)         // release
#define VERIFY(x) (assert(x)) // debug
```

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to tell without looking at the actual code that is causing the issue. My guess: you are evaluating an expression with side-effects within an `ASSERT()`. For instance, `ASSERT( ++i < someotherthing )` whithin a loop. You could confirm by temporary modifying the macro definition to just `expr` on `NDEBUG` builds. After confirming this is the cause, go to each and every `ASSERT` call you are issuing to ensure that the expressions are side-effects free.

Comment: This is probably the second most common reason (after optimizations) for differences between debug and release builds.

Comment: Thanks for answering, just one question. Would it be good practice to just `#define ASSERT(expr) (expr)` (like what Kerrek SB had mentioned) for non-debugs, and just not worry about side effects from there on? I have a feeling this would make my code more readable.

Comment: @AutoBotAM: If you call that `ASSERT` `VERIFY` instead, then sure, go ahead. But don't redefine `ASSERT`, people know and expect it to not evaluate the expression on `NDEBUG` builds.